# Whats wrong by the name in front of mail address in footnote?

Tags: elsarticle

Can someone help me by saying whats wrong with latex in the `elsarticle` class considering the below MWE?

```
\documentclass[review,authoryear,12pt]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\journal{International Journal of Engineering Science}
\author[1,2]{H. M. SHodja\corref{4}}
\author[3]{A. Ordookhani}
\cortext[4]{Corresponding author. Tel.: +98-21-66164209. Fax: +98-21-66014828.}
\ead{shodja@sharif.edu}
\ead{ordookhani@kish.sharif.edu}
\address[1]{Department of Civil Engineering, Sharif University of Technology, P.O. Box 11155-9313, Tehran, Iran}
\address[2]{Institute for Nanoscience and Nanotechnology, Sharif University of Technology, P.O. Box 11155-9161, Tehran, Iran}
\address[3]{Department of Civil Engineering, School of Science and Engineering, Sharif University of Technology, International Campus, P.O. Box 79417-76655, Kish Island, Iran}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The desired output should be:

> Shodja@sharif.edu (H.M.Shodja) and ordookhani@kish.sharif.edu (A. Ordookhani)

Comment: as posted it generates `! LaTeX Error: \begin{frontmatter} on input line 13 ended by \end{document}.`

Comment: you probably have to state the address after the author, so \author \ead \author \ead

Comment: @barbarabeeton yep so I saw:-) (I deleted original comment)

Comment: it works, tnx @Bort

Comment: @Bort -- make that an answer, please.

Comment: Pages 3-4 of [Elsevier Examples](http://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/56843/elsdoc-1.pdf) provide short examples of what is needed and confirms Bort's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comment turned answer: you (probably) have to state the address after the author, so `\author \ead \author \ead`